# SQL Server only loads data into one of the files in a filegroup

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 files in filegroup PRIMARY, and when I bulkcopy, it always inserts the data into just one of the files--and it is the same file every time. The other two files are always empty. Did I miss anything?

SQL Server 2016 version: 13.0.1601.5

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to efficiently help you. Please edit your question and include a [mcve] of the problem, so a person attempting to answer can see what you might be missing.   
Also, see [ask] for how to ask questions in order to have the best chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @RichardII, I think that question is quite clear. The first url in your message is broken.

Comment: @Alexander, thanks, I fixed the links. I'm glad the question is clear to you, although I doubt it based on your first word "Perhaps".  We'll soon see if you guessed right. :-)

Comment: @Alexander, you were right :-)   After reading your the link you referenced, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you see this by the growth of files. This can be adjusted by a new database-scoped setting:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDb
MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES
GO
```

The same thing can be achieved on an instance level via trace flag:

```
DBCC TRACEON(1117,-1)
```

Worth to mention that trace flag approach available in older versions..

Extra reference:

- http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/day-6trace-flag-1117-auto-grow-equally-in-all-data-file/